# Is Mongo 3.4 using indexes for this query or not?

Tags: mongodb, indices

I'm using a sharded replica set. Have one large collection with the following index:

```
{ 
    "shop" : 1, 
    "email" : 1
}
```

I'm trying to find the best way of querying each element one by one:

```
db.user.explain('executionStats').find({shop:151, email:{$exists:true}}, {limit:1}))
```

and the results are the following.

My questions are:
Is the query using the index?
If yes, how can I read from this **explain** result?

Second:
is better to use this query, loop the cursor, then query again

> .find({shop:151, email:{$exists:true}}, {limit:100}))

or

> .findOne({shop:151, email:{$exists:true}}))

in a continuous loop?

```
{ 
"queryPlanner" : {
    "plannerVersion" : NumberInt(1), 
    "namespace" : "vt4users.user", 
    "indexFilterSet" : false, 
    "parsedQuery" : {
        "$and" : [
            {
                "shop" : {
                    "$eq" : NumberInt(151)
                }
            }, 
            {
                "email" : {
                    "$exists" : true
                }
            }
        ]
    }, 
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "PROJECTION", 
        "transformBy" : {
            "limit" : NumberInt(1)
        }, 
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH", 
            "filter" : {
                "email" : {
                    "$exists" : true
                }
            }, 
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN", 
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "shop" : NumberInt(1), 
                    "email" : NumberInt(1)
                }, 
                "indexName" : "shop_1_email_1", 
                "isMultiKey" : false, 
                "isUnique" : false, 
                "isSparse" : true, 
                "isPartial" : false, 
                "indexVersion" : NumberInt(1), 
                "direction" : "forward", 
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "shop" : [
                        "[151.0, 151.0]"
                    ], 
                    "email" : [
                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }, 
    "rejectedPlans" : [

    ]
}, 
"executionStats" : {
    "executionSuccess" : true, 
    "nReturned" : NumberInt(3), 
    "executionTimeMillis" : NumberInt(0), 
    "totalKeysExamined" : NumberInt(3), 
    "totalDocsExamined" : NumberInt(3), 
    "executionStages" : {
        "stage" : "PROJECTION", 
        "nReturned" : NumberInt(3), 
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : NumberInt(0), 
        "works" : NumberInt(4), 
        "advanced" : NumberInt(3), 
        "needTime" : NumberInt(0), 
        "needYield" : NumberInt(0), 
        "saveState" : NumberInt(0), 
        "restoreState" : NumberInt(0), 
        "isEOF" : NumberInt(1), 
        "invalidates" : NumberInt(0), 
        "transformBy" : {
            "limit" : NumberInt(1)
        }, 
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH", 
            "filter" : {
                "email" : {
                    "$exists" : true
                }
            }, 
            "nReturned" : NumberInt(3), 
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : NumberInt(0), 
            "works" : NumberInt(4), 
            "advanced" : NumberInt(3), 
            "needTime" : NumberInt(0), 
            "needYield" : NumberInt(0), 
            "saveState" : NumberInt(0), 
            "restoreState" : NumberInt(0), 
            "isEOF" : NumberInt(1), 
            "invalidates" : NumberInt(0), 
            "docsExamined" : NumberInt(3), 
            "alreadyHasObj" : NumberInt(0), 
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN", 
                "nReturned" : NumberInt(3), 
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : NumberInt(0), 
                "works" : NumberInt(4), 
                "advanced" : NumberInt(3), 
                "needTime" : NumberInt(0), 
                "needYield" : NumberInt(0), 
                "saveState" : NumberInt(0), 
                "restoreState" : NumberInt(0), 
                "isEOF" : NumberInt(1), 
                "invalidates" : NumberInt(0), 
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "shop" : NumberInt(1), 
                    "email" : NumberInt(1)
                }, 
                "indexName" : "shop_1_email_1", 
                "isMultiKey" : false, 
                "isUnique" : false, 
                "isSparse" : true, 
                "isPartial" : false, 
                "indexVersion" : NumberInt(1), 
                "direction" : "forward", 
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "shop" : [
                        "[151.0, 151.0]"
                    ], 
                    "email" : [
                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                    ]
                }, 
                "keysExamined" : NumberInt(3), 
                "dupsTested" : NumberInt(0), 
                "dupsDropped" : NumberInt(0), 
                "seenInvalidated" : NumberInt(0)
            }
        }
    }
}, 
"serverInfo" : {
    "host" : "host", 
    "port" : NumberInt(27017), 
    "version" : "3.2.11", 
    "gitVersion" : "009580ad490190ba33d1c6253ebd8d91808923e4"
}, 
"ok" : NumberInt(1)
```

}

Comment: You are using 3.2, not 3.4 as in the question title. It doesn't matter though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is using the index. You can see that in the `inputStage`

```
"stage" : "IXSCAN"
```

You can [check it in the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/) to better understand its meaning.

Regarding your second question, if you want to fetch all results, looping with findOne is NOT better (performance wise) than doing the query normally.

Comment: indeed, I copied from local mongo. Doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: and indeed I ended up fetching with limit instead of find_one